# NSView and CALayer

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, core-animation

On Cocoa, in order to ensure that a view has it's own layer, you should set `wantsLayer` to `true`.

**What is the exact difference with `wantsLayer` and `wantsUpdateLayer` ?**
From what I understand `wantsLayer` causes the view to start using a layer, while `wantsUpdateLayer` changes the way the view is drawn (by calling `updateLayer` instead of `draw`).

What would be the use of setting `wantsLayer` to true without setting `wantsUpdateLayer` to true either ?
Do you still need to set `wantsLayer` to `true` if you have `wantsUpdateLayer` set to true ?

**Where should I interact with my views layer ?**
Is this right that you should only interact with your layer within the `updateLayer` function ? Does this applies to every property and method of `CALayer` ? For instance if I want to add a sublayer, should this be done in `updateLayer` too ?

**EDIT**
Additionally, the latest AppKit release notes states that :

> Apps targeting macOS 10.14 should prefer the wantsUpdateLayer property
>   over the wantsLayer property.

So does this mean that on macOS 10.14 you  don't actually need to use wantsLayer if you are already using wantsUpdateLayer ?

Comment: Check out [WWDC 2013 Session 215: Optimizing Drawing and Scrolling on OS X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/215/) for info about `wantsUpdateLayer`. Then check out [WWDC 2018 Session 209: What's New in Cocoa for macOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/209/) for some updated information.

Comment: @robmayoff I will watch them ! Thank you !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The wantsLayer property tells whether your NSView will be backed by a layer or not. By default NSViews are **not** layer backed by default. So if you need a layer (e.g. for animations), you need to specify it.

The wantsUpdateLayer is really different. NSView can update their content in two (exclusive) ways :

- by calling the drawRect: method
- by calling the updateLayer method

By default wantsUpdateLayer returns NO, and therefore, drawRect: is called. but if you set wantsUpdateLayer to return YES (and if your view is layer-backed), then updateLayer will be called instead.

updatelayer can be much faster than drawRect: if you can update your view content by modifying layer attributes

So to answer you questions :

- You want to set wantsLayer to YES and wantsUpdateLayer to NO if you need to do fancy drawing in drawRect: (remember, updateLayer is faster but you can only modify the layer attributes)
- Yes, you need wantsLayer to YES if you set wantsUpdateLayer to YES
- You can interact with your layer attribute wherever you want, including from drawRect:

Comment: Thank you ! When reading the documentation I see that "If the wantsUpdateLayer method returns false, you should not interact with the underlying layer object directly. Instead, use the methods of this class to make any changes to the view and its layer. If wantsUpdateLayer returns true, it is acceptable (and appropriate) to modify the layer *in the view’s updateLayer() method.*" doesn't this mean that I cannot update my layer properties outside?

Comment: MMmmhh... I guess it all depends on what we put behind "layer attribute". Note that the doc you refer to says "modify the layer", not "layer attribute". So basically, if you only want to change the radius of the corners or the background colour (which I call attribute), you can do that from drawRect:. I don't think there is a point in doing anything more complex. Now, if you provide your own subclass of CALayer, and/or compute some bitmap content to provide to the layer (which I "guess" is behind the wording "modify the layer"), then indeed, updateLayer is the best place.

Comment: May I recommend you to have a look at: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/SettingUpLayerObjects/SettingUpLayerObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH13-SW14 section "Providing a Layer’s Contents" and following. I know its a bit out of date, but...

Comment: **This answer isn't correct for macOS 10.14.** [WWDC 2018 Session 209: What's New in Cocoa for macOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/209/) answers some of the questions.

Comment: The discussion for LayerBacking begins at 22:42.

Comment: @AirXygène updateLayer is not called if you provide a CALayer subclass